# php и header нужна помощь

Tags: php

Можно ли в `header()` передать свой список параметров, к примеру если бы я написал вот так `controlPanel.php?login=admin`

Comment: Приведите более подробный пример и детали, того что вы хотите сделать плз.

Comment: вы про `header("Location: controlPanel.php?login=admin")` или про что?

Comment: @teran да про это

Comment: Если вы вдруг попробовали, и у вас не работает перенаправление, значит перед этим где то уже выводился какой-то текст на страницу. Обычно при этом показывается предупреждение о том, что заголовки уже были отправлены.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет header() не может добавить данные в URL. Можно добавить только заголовки ответа сервера. Например тип файла или кодировка. Можно и что-то свое добавить, но и обрабатывать это надо самим.

Comment: можно пример как добавить что-то своё и это обрабатывать?